# React native all list items not rendering memory problem or anything else?

Tags: android, react-native, memory, navigation, react-navigation

It is an e-commerce app built to react native in which some screens of loading products are working fine loading fluently(we are using Listview). but, two main screens where we want to load our products with images very fluently, there is a problem, images are not loading there.

Actually, the code we used is kind of similar code on all screens but the list is not loading fluently, also lagging the app. app is available on google play store. [Shopcon App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shopcon&hl=en)

I also tried `Flatlist`, `ListView` and many another solutions like `removeClippedSubviews={false}`, `removeClippedSubviews={true}` , `android:largeHeap="true"` but no any results. also checked many other stack-overflow questions and GitHub repositories so many have the same problem but yet there is no valid and problem-solving solution available.

I am in confusion that is it a problem in any component of react native, an issue with a memory or a problem of navigation between in screens(I am using react navigation)

I am attaching two gifs of the same app wherein first gif all is loading very fluently. but in second gif images of product not rendering.

Kindly help for this bug/error/problem just stuck on it. If you know any react native core team member kindly let them know this problem.

So many thanks in advance

here are the gifs

[1st gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=108p1aBZvU9ppmplGjDOael9OCoD9xMWK)

[2nd gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11Wm9EtZGId7vB9lScldWEpajWKrFZf-P)

Comment: have you checked in release apk? because in debug this is a very common issue. but after creating a release apk flatlist and listview work fluently.

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani in release app this problem is occurring. You can check it, app available on play-store link given above.

Comment: @DivyaSIngh code is too much lengthy I cant put it here but I uploaded file on drive here are the links of them 

screen 1 (code of 1st gif) where all is working fluently  `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eR-pg4zb3awE1Q09MBvuqu1UVJm4Ckn2` 

screen 2 (code of 2nd gif) where nothing is loading `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zwzTmhnsgAHqDsYIhM8bxpRdTIByhfpD`